# Why is this if statement not working in twig?

Tags: theming, 9

It's a bidirectional D9 site where I removed **dir=rtl** from my theme's **html.html.twig** with an if statement and it's working fine. I did that to avoid an MS browsers bug ignoring **position: sticky** in css if there was any dir="rtl" in either html or body tags. I did so in **html.html.twig** with this code:

```
{% if html_attributes['dir'] == 'rtl' %}
  <html{{ html_attributes|without('dir') }}>
{% elseif html_attributes['dir'] == 'ltr' %}
  <html{{ html_attributes }}>
{% endif %}
```

So now, when the site is in English (or any LTR lang) the html tag has a dir="ltr" attribute in it but none if the dir is rtl. That's working well.

I added the **dir** attribute to **page.html.twig** #page-warpper like this:

```
{% apply spaceless %}
{% if html_attributes['dir'] == 'ltr' %}
  <div id="page-wrapper" dir="ltr"> 
{% else %}
  <div id="page-wrapper" dir="rtl"> 
{% endif %}
{% endapply %}  
  <div id="page"> ......
```

This isn't working. Only the rtl direction is applied to the #page-wrapper regardless of the site's direction/ language. I added the spaceless filter later as I thought it might be an indentation issue but no change still.

I also tried this but not working either:

```
{% if html_attributes['dir'] %}
  <div id="page-wrapper" dir="ltr"> 
{% else %}
  <div id="page-wrapper" dir="rtl"> 
{% endif %}
```

Thank you for any views.
And sure, I did **drush cr** after each twig edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `html_attributes` is not available in a page template. To make it available copy this code from [template_preprocess_html()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/9.0.x) to your page preprocess hook:

```
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  $variables['html_attributes'] = new Attribute();
  $language_interface = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
  $variables['html_attributes']['lang'] = $language_interface->getId();
  $variables['html_attributes']['dir'] = $language_interface->getDirection();

}
```